# How to append a missing line only by comparing 2 columns in 2 different files

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files

file1 (reference file)

```
xxx xxxxx 00    
xxx xxxxx 01    
xxx xxxxx 02    
xxx xxxxx 03    
xxx xxxxx 04    
xxx xxxxx 00    
xxx xxxxx 01     
xxx xxxxx 02    
xxx xxxxx 03    
xxx xxxxx 04
```

file2

```
12345 2021/04/02 00    
1212  2021/04/02 01    
12123 2021/04/02 02    
12123 2021/04/02 04    
1223  2021/04/03 01    
124   2021/04/03 02    
123   2021/04/03 03
```

And I want to compare last field on each file and append the missing row from first file(my reference file)

For example I want the out put to be

```
12345 2021/04/02 00    
1212  2021/04/02 01    
12123 2021/04/02 02    
xxx   xxxxx      03    
12123 2021/04/02 04    
xxx   xxxxx      00     
1223  2021/04/03 01    
124   2021/04/03 02    
123   2021/04/03 03    
xxx   xxxxx      04
```

I have tried using `awk -F ' ' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next}a[$2] && $1>=00' test2.txt test1.txt`, which appends the missing third value from the file1 but output removes the data I need (2nd and 3rd fields) as well.

Comment: Why are several lines identical in file1?

Comment: 2nd file generated via log information, 3rd field shows the hour and when there is no data for a given hour it is not showing in the 2nd file. so I want to keep file1 as a reference and add the missing lines to file 2.

Comment: That part was clear but why does `xxx xxxxx 03`, for example, appear twice in file1 though? Are the 2 lines really identical or not? If not, please update your example to reflect that and tell us which should be used in the output - the first occurrence or the 2nd one?

Comment: I don't need the X's think of the file1's field3 as a pattern and you can clearly see that pattern's disrupted in file2's field3. what I need is to append the missing numbers that pattern in file1, without loosing data in file2.

Comment: (1) Might file2 ever skip multiple consecutive values?  (2) Can file2 ever skip an entire cycle?  (3) Is it the case that every line in file1 is identical except for the third field? If so, you should say so, as that may make the problem somewhat easier. If not, you should show it with different values. The current (fake) version may make testing harder.  (4) You seem to be claiming that the command you tried produced *some* output, albeit incomplete. When I run it, I get no output whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```c
cat file2 | awk '!(1 in f) {if ((getline l < "-") == 1) split(l, f)} $3!=f[3] {print;next} {print l; delete f}' file1 | column -t
```

Note that the script expects `file1` as *argument* to awk, while expects `file2` as its *standard input*. I used a "useless use of cat" to show that more explicitly, but naturally you can rather provide it as a `< file2` redirection instead. In fact you might even embed the filename in the script itself, as `"file2"` in place of the `"-"` to the `getline`, but this way is a bit more flexible.

Also note that the two files are expected to start "synchronized" in terms of field3 values, or possibly with `file2` "ahead" of `file1` if that is sensible for your use case.

The script alone broken down for readability, and verbosely commented for explanation:

```c
# Check if our `real_fields` array is not existent.
# NOTE: we use the `<index> in <array>` construct
# in order to force awk treat `real_fields` name as an
# array (instead of as a scalar as it would by default)
# and build it in an empty state
!(1 in real_fields) {
    # get the next line (if any) from the "real" file
    if ((getline real_line < "-") == 1)
        # split that line in separate fields populating
        # our `real_fields` array
        split(real_line, real_fields)
        # awk split function creates an array with numeric
        # indexes for each field found as per FS separator
}
# if field3 of the current line of the "reference"
# file does not match the current line of the "real" file..
$3!=real_fields[3] {
    # print current line of "reference" file
    print
    # go reading next line of "reference" file thus
    # skipping the final awk pattern
    next
}
# final awk pattern, we get here only if the pattern
# above did not match, i.e. if field3 values from both
# files match
{
    # print current line of "real" file
    print real_line
    # delete our real_fields array, thus triggering
    # the fetching of the next line of "real" file as
    # performed by the first awk pattern
    delete real_fields
}
```

Comment: You sir are life saver, thank you so much! My headache is cured, if you can explain the code I'd be even more grateful:)

Comment: @darkfury47 Sure, see my edit. I've also fixed an overlooked bug wrt eof condition, which would trigger if your `file1`'s field3 would overlap `file2`s values

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the order of the array, or awk will re-order your lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
}
NR==FNR {
    a[i++,$3]=$0
    next
} 
{
    for (c in a) {
        split(c, s, SUBSEP)
        if (s[2] == $3) {
            print $0
            getline
        } else {
            print a[c]
        }
    }
}
```

```
./script.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: This works for the example I posted, I didn't posted the entire thing because it was too long. In real life scenario file1 will have 00 to 23 times 7 (third field) instead of  00-04X2 and file2 will sometimes miss these third field values. would you be able to adjust the code kindly according to that scenario?

Comment: I need something to test with, add them to your Q, and I'll try to implement them.

Comment: Please put your email here and I will send you the both files, since I can't attach them here.

Comment: @darkfury47: Allo, allo, free scripting service. Post your email here and wait to see if someone ask for your file.

Comment: darkfury47@gmail.com